# undefined method `primary_key' for StatusesController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

**Model**

[image]

**Controller**

[image]

**Error**

[image]

**Application Trace**

```
app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb:35:in `update'
```

**Schema**

[image]

Comment: Are you using "id" as the primary field for your tables?

Comment: No, never. I thought that Rails use "id" by default. I have posted my Schema.rb, is that right or I should add "id" column?

Comment: what does your `getResource` method do?

Comment: The schema looks correct

Comment: @j03w Question updated with full code

Comment: ok one more thing… full stack trace please

Comment: ok, done PS: Do you receive a notification if I update my question post?

Comment: only if you @ mention me… full trace please I think yours only show framework trace not the entire try click on **Full Trace** and update your question again please.

Comment: @j03w Yes, it's "full trace" in both examples

Comment: where is your `current_user` get instantiated?

Comment: @j03w It came from "devise".

Comment: I cut the part about "current_user" same error

Comment: Please could you show your user model.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean Done. I've delete the "example n.1" because there was something else that mess up something. I leave Example n.2

Comment: Try adding (status_params) at the end of the @status.comments.create line.  Your status_params method will probably also have to require(:comment).permit(:user, :comment)

Comment: Probably you right, I have only  params.require(:status).permit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `status_params` method to add:

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:user, :comment)
```

and then change all the places you try to update comments to include `(status_params)` at the end.